# recvfrom() doesn't get any request from any remote client

Tags: udp

I have written a udp server which receives client requests using a `recvfrom()` socket system call, this call receives requests from localhost only, no remote host requests are seen by the `recvfrom()` call. I tried capturing packets on the receivng port and I can see the packets coming from remote server, but the request don't reach `recvfrom()`, what could be the matter?

Comment: You're probably only listening on localhost. Impossible to tell without seeing your code, or the output of `netstat -an | grep the_port_you_use`.

Comment: @Mat  
I have two different sockets listening on the same port (one for TCP and one for UDP)    

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      31196/agentd    
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:32000           0.0.0.0:*                           31196/agentd

Comment: Already checked firewall configurations? "Seeing" packets with tcpdump doesn't mean that they pass a firewall if one is active.

Comment: Right, solved, firewall is blocking the udp packets. But I dont see any problem with TCP packets even though the firewall is running. Thanks #ktf

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure a firewall isn't active. `tcpdump` can see packets as they arrive on an interface, before a firewall has processed and dropped them

<sub>(Adapted from [ktf's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24379/recvfrom-doesnt-get-any-request-from-any-remote-client#comment32685_24379))</sub>